# Decrypt md5 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encryption

i try to make function for lost password in my website using vb.net the code below is fore encrypt

```
 Function getMD5Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
    Dim md5Obj As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)

    bytesToHash = md5Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)

    Dim strResult As String = ""

    For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
        strResult += b.ToString("x2")
    Next

    Return strResult
End Function
```

Comment: You should consider to built in an option, for entering a new password when the old one has been lost, not retrieving the old. Since that would be considered a security issue.

Comment: Gonna refer you over to crypto. MD5 is broken. Its easy to use and built into .Net. However, you should read this as I think you are new to security. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/what-is-the-recommended-replacement-for-md5 and this site for a discussion regarding salt. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: 1) You should not use a fast hash like MD5 as password hash. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for what you should use. 2) You're silently replacing any non ASCII character by a questionmark, reducing the password entropy. Use `UTF-8` not `ASCII` 3) Don't send the original password during password reset. Send a link with a one time token and allow the user to set a new password when they follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD5 is a hashing algorithm, not a bidirectional encryption system.

For lost password, you should send a password reset token instead of sending the end user the password.

Comment: so what i need to do?

Comment: i need to do this more than the other @daniel A. White

Comment: Ahmed, as Daniel said, this shouldn't, and cannot be done. You would only be able to send the actual hash, not the decrypted hash. A hash is one way encryption. To verify if passwords match, the stored hash and the entered hash are compared. You will need an alternative to your method, but again, no one recommends your present path.